# Presenting good work in a better way

Tags: performance, disability, work-from-home

I work at a really great company were my boss and even my boss's boss really care for me. 
Because i'm mentally ill, they do stuff like cover for me in talks to the company owner. I pay them back by doing the needed work in half the time that's needed and if they need something "yesterday" they have it before they wake up.

Effectively i am paid for 40 hours on site but do 15 hours on site and deliver 60 hours of work every week.
THIS IS NOT ABOUT OVER TIME.
The company owner is now demanding that i "work more" eg be on site more.
My boss already tried to present the flat numbers of how much better i perform off-site but the owner says he "wants to know his employees better"..
My boss and i want to really work this out as smooth as possible, so the question is, are there any KPI or stuff we could buzzword to the owner?

Comment: What country are you from?

Comment: And also, are you able to get a letter from a medical professional that has the advice that your site-time should be limited

Comment: Is "want to know employees better" the real reason? Or does he just want warm bodies and butts in seats? If the former, consider meeting with him informally for a chat. If the latter, probably time to update your resume.

Comment: Do you do 15 hours onsite and 45 hours at home? Or do you get 60 hours of work done in 15 hours onsite?

Answer (score 2):

> they do stuff like cover for me in talks to the company owner

This is your bosses problem, you cannot solve it and he already knows your worth. It will come down to how much faith the owner has in the bosses judgement.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is also correct -- this is your boss's problem.

Your team should have a means of measuring what everyone is producing, even if only to be used for an annual performance review. Your boss needs to run those numbers for you and your peers -- people at the same payscale, etc. -- and provide those to your boss.

There are plenty of disabled people who have work restrictions, and your case is sort of unique and sort of not unique. But mostly, your boss needs to prove to his boss that you are delivering the correct value for your compensation.